How would you address the claim that the messiah's lineage could be through the mother?
A little context: I am on a Facebook group where Christians and Jews debate, and we were discussing how Christ could be the messiah, when he wasn't directly through the male lineage of David, in which a Christian response stating that the messiah could be through the lineage of David through the mother, how would you respond?
I have posted the response below:

No, Numbers 1:18 itself doesn't definitively establish that lineage
and status are determined solely by the father. The passage focuses on
paternal lineage for the census, likely due to the patriarchal
structure of the time. However, it doesn't negate the concept of
matrilineal descent established elsewhere in Jewish tradition.
In traditional Judaism, lineage for determining Jewish identity is
traced through the mother. This is known as matrilineal descent. If
your mother is Jewish, you are considered Jewish as well. If your
father is Jewish but your mother is not, you are not considered Jewish
according to traditional halakha (Jewish law).
Rabbinic interpretations of several passages in the Torah are used to
support matrilineal descent in Judaism. Here are two examples:
Deuteronomy 7:3-4: This passage warns against intermarriage and its
potential consequence of turning one's children away from following
God's teachings. The Talmud interprets the emphasis on "your son" in
the context of a Jewish mother as implying that only children of
Jewish mothers are considered inherently part of the covenant.
Exodus 21:4: This verse speaks of a Hebrew slave who is freed. If he
has a Canaanite wife during his slavery, his children remain enslaved.
This is interpreted to mean that the children's status follows their
mother's non-Jewish status.


Your confusion is because you are not thinking about the emphasis of being a  descendent from the House of King David and Solomon properly. The focus of the patrilineal descent is because it is about the Laws of Inheritance. The Monarchy from the House of David and Solomon is an inheritance. Daughters do not inherit over any of their equally entitled male heirs. See the laws of Inheritance for details: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Inheritances.1.1?lang=bi

Jewish status is matrilinear, but tribal identity is patrilnear. Again -- the Hasmoneans were critiqued for taking the Second Temple throne because their tribal/patrilinear line was through Aaron (Levi), not David (Judah). Why didn't they just find someone whose mom was Davidic? Because that doesn't work.

Despite claims of being God's son, wouldn't Jesus halachically be Joseph's son because they were married at the time of his birth and Mary wasn't known to be secluded with another man?

Same thing for all the kings of the North Kingdom in the First Temple era. They were non-Davidic by their father's lineage, so that made them "non-Davidic kings." All of these claims -- adoption, matrilinear descent, "as-if" -- show a complete lack of understanding of halacha. (And yes, once someone departs from halacha, they can justify whatever they want.)

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82239/must-moshiach-ben-duvid-be-in-direct-patrilineal-descent/
